# When I try to login as admin, it redirects back to login activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As you can see this is Login Activity, for users and admin. User login is working properly, but when I try to login admin, the application throws an error at onDataChange.

Error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(CustomClassMapper.java:426)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:217)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.example.cardview.LoginActivity$4.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:128)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText InputPhoneNumber, InputPassword;
    private Button LoginButton;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private TextView AdminLink, NotAdminLink;

    private String parentDbName = "Users";
    private CheckBox chkBoxRememberMe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_phone_number_input);
        AdminLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.admin_panel_link);
        NotAdminLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.not_admin_panel_link);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        chkBoxRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_me_chkb);
        Paper.init(this);

        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                LoginUser();
            }
        });

        AdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               LoginButton.setText( "Login Admin" );
               AdminLink.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
               NotAdminLink.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
               parentDbName = "Admins";
            }
        });

        NotAdminLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                LoginButton.setText( "Login" );
                AdminLink.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                NotAdminLink.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                parentDbName = "Users";
            }
        });

    }

    private void LoginUser()
    {
        String phone = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your phone number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Login Account");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are checking the credentials.");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();

            AllowAccessToAccount(phone, password);
        }
    }

    private void AllowAccessToAccount(final String phone, final String password)
    {
        if(chkBoxRememberMe.isChecked())
        {
            Paper.book().write(Prevalent.UserPhoneKey, phone);
            Paper.book().write(Prevalent.UserPasswordKey, password);
        }


        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).exists())
                {
                    Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);

                    if (usersData.getPhone().equals(phone))
                    {
                        if (usersData.getPassword().equals(password))
                        {
                            if (parentDbName.equals("Admins"))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome Admin, You are logged in Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminAddNewProductActivity.class);
                                Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = usersData;
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else if(parentDbName.equals("Users"))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                Prevalent.currentOnlineUser = usersData;
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password is incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Account with this " + phone + " number do not exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Error shown in thus line : Users usersData = dataSnapshot.child(parentDbName).child(phone).getValue(Users.class);

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the database contains a numeric value in one of the properties, but your `Users` class declares the same property as a `String`. Firebase will not perform an automatic conversion for you here, as it would lead to problems when writing back to the database.

It's impossible to say which specific property is causing the problem based on the information provided, but if you compare the JSON in the database with your Java `Users` class it should be pretty easy to spot.